# Integral extension of fields is a finite vector space extension

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory

I want to show that if $E$ and $F$ are fields, and $E$ is an integral extension of $F$, then $E$ as a vector space over $F$ has finite dimension. Does anyone have a proof of this, or can reference one?

Thanks.

Comment: This is basically Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

Comment: I am trying to prove this in order to prove the Weak Nullstellensatz

Comment: See this link, under "Corollary, Weak Nullstellensatz": https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~sjw47/Lecture16-18.pdf
. It concludes with "A is integral over k as required", but that is not exactly what it set out to show (that the extension is finite). I am trying to equate these two statements.

Comment: @Daven: You might find [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15226/elementary-interesting-proofs-of-the-nullstellensatz) useful.

Comment: It seems to me that an algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ is integral over $\mathbb Q$, and that it is infinite dimensional as a $\mathbb Q$-vector space.

Comment: Yes I think this is correct. My question is missing the hypothesis "E is finitely generated as an F-algebra", which would make the statement true. Thank you.